# How to reverse a Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse

I am working on a project for my Data Structures class that asks me to write a class to implement a linked list of ints.

> - Use an inner class for the Node.
> - Include the methods below.
> - Write a tester to enable you to test all of the methods with whatever data you want in any order.

I have to create a method called "public LinkedListOfInts reverse()". This method is meant to "Return a copy of your Linked List but in reverse order." I have my code for this method down below. However, when I try to reverse a list it only prints the head. For Example, if I have a list like "[16, 1, 8, 7, 10, 10, 14, 17, 11, 4,] and I try to reverse it my output is [ 16, ]. Does someone know how correct my code so I can reverse a linked list?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListOfInts {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(LinkedListOfInts other) {
        Node tail = null;
        for (Node n = other.head; n != null; n = n.nextNode) {
            if (tail == null)
                this.head = tail = new Node(n.value, null);
            else {
                tail.nextNode = new Node(n.value, null);
                tail = tail.nextNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(int[] other) {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[other.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < other.length; index++) {
            nodes[index] = new Node(other[index], null);
            if (index > 0) {
                nodes[index - 1].nextNode = nodes[index];
            }
        }

        head = nodes[0];
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(int N, int low, int high) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            this.addToFront(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
    }

    public void addToFront(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts reverse() {
        if (head == null)
            return null;
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;
        Node nextNode = null;
        while (current != null) {
            nextNode = current.nextNode;
            current.nextNode = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = nextNode;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = " ";
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode)
            result += ptr.value + " ";
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts(10, 1, 20);
        LinkedListOfInts copy = new LinkedListOfInts(list);
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("1. Reverse");
            System.out.println("2. toString");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 11:
                System.out.println("Reverse the List");
                System.out.println(copy.reverse());
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("toString");
                System.out.println(list.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In reverse method, you declare return type is LinkedListOfInts but actually you return variable previous which is a LinkedListOfInts.Node type. LinkedListOfInts.Node and LinkedListOfInts is not the same. Just comment about syntax, I haven't check logic yet

Comment: @luanvu Well that I figured but I don't know how do I change it so I can return the correct variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for reversing your LinkedList. Keep in mind that you are not copying the content of the LinkedList. So if you reverse the list, the original list's head is now the tail and returns only one int.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListOfInts{
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node{" +
                    "value=" + value +
                    ", nextNode=" + nextNode +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(LinkedListOfInts other) {
        System.out.println(other.tail);
        head = other.head;
        tail = other.tail;

        System.out.println(this);

    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(int N, int low, int high) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            this.addToFront(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
        }
        Node node=head;
        while(node.nextNode!=null){
            node = node.nextNode;
        }
        tail = node;
    }

    public void addToFront(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts reverse() {
        Node previous = null;
        Node curr = head;
        Node nex;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            nex = curr.nextNode;
            curr.nextNode = previous;
            previous = curr;
            curr = nex;
        }
        head = previous;
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(" ");
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode)
            result.append(ptr.value).append(" ");
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts(10, 1, 20);
        LinkedListOfInts copy = new LinkedListOfInts(list);
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("1. Reverse");
            System.out.println("2. toString");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Reverse the List");
                    System.out.println(copy.reverse());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("toString");
                    System.out.println(list);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```